# Objective C - Set Label Properties on UIView Subclass from View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my app I have a custom Google Map pin marker designed in a Nib file. Part of the pin marker will display an estimated arrival time.

Here is how I am loading the Nib, and attempting to set a custom time:

```
self.markerPinFromNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PinWithTimeView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
self.markerPinFromNib.estTime.text = @"20";
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
-[UIView estTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

PinWithTimeView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PinWithTimeView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *rotateCircle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *estTime;

@end
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In your PinWithTimeView.h

```
@interface PinWithTimeView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *rotateCircle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *estTime;
-(id)initWithEstTime:(NSString*)time;
@end
```

In your PinWithTimeView.m

```
-(id)initWithEstTime:(NSString*)time{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PinWithTimeView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.estTime.text = time;

    }
    return self;
}
```

In your controller

```
self.markerPinFromNib = [[PinWithTimeView alloc]initWithEstTime:@"20"];
```

Comment: Still getting "[UIView estTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" ... any idea why?

Comment: Can you please share the line where the code is getting crashed. Please use breakpoint for debugging

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the instance from nib to `PinWithTimeView` in force. Like this:

```
((PinWithTimeView *)self.markerPinFromNib).estTime.text = @"20";
```

Because `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` will return a array include `UIView` instances.